# Rename directories based on matching and appending column data

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I want to rename directories based on matching information from columns of the CSV file.

For example, the columns in the csv file with repeated some rows looks like this:

```
1111,ABC1
1111,ABC1
2222,DFG2
3333,FEG1
3333,FEG1
4444,TTG2
```

The existing directories are with following names:

```
1111 2222 3333 4444
```

I want to rename these directories by matching with column `1` and appending the corresponding column `2` information along with it.

I read the columns as follows:

```
col1_id=$(awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1}' "$somefile" | sed 1d | awk '!a[$0]++')
col2_id=$(awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' "$somefile" | sed 1d | awk '!a[$0]++')
```

I tried to map the columns and append as follows:

```
cnt=${#col1_id[@]}
for ((i=0;i<cnt;i++)); 
do
    mv "{$col1_id[i]}" "${col1_id[i]}_${col2_id[i]}"
done
```

However, I am not getting the desired output. My output directories should be with names.

```
1111_ABC1 2222_DFG2 3333_FEG1 4444_TTG2
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question based on your comment

Comment: You say you have a CSV but your sample input is space-separated, not comma-separated, please [edit] your question to make sure the text and example reflect the same information.

Comment: I have edited accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU tools, you could do something like:

```
<file.csv uniq | gawk -F, '{printf "%s\0%s_%s\0", $1, $1, $2}' |
  xargs -r0n2 mv -T --
```

Where `gawk` prints `1111` and `1111_ABC1` NUL-delimited records for each each `1111,ABC1` line of input, and `xargs` takes 2 of them at a time to pass to `mv -T --`.

That assumes the duplicated lines are adjacent. If not, use `sort -u` instead of `uniq` or do the deduplicating in `gawk`:

```
<file.csv gawk -F, '!seen[$1]++ {printf "%s\0%s_%s\0", $1, $1, $2}' |
  xargs -r0n2 mv -T --
```

(here skipping the lines for which the first field has already been seen).

Comment: This is magic!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do something like this (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A map
while IFS=, read -r old new rest_if_any_ignored; do
    map["$old"]="$new"
done < file

for old in *; do
    if [[ -n "${map[$old]}" ]]; then
        new="${map[$old]}"
        mv -- "$old" "${old}_${new}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about this solution?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's been over a year, I'm not going to revisit it now.